# Why can I not run Playground in Gatsby 5 as it was in Gatsby 4 using GATSBY_GRAPHQL_IDE=playground gatsby develop?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, graphql-playground

I'm trying to run Graphql Playground in Gatsby.

My config:

```
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "GATSBY_GRAPHQL_IDE=playground gatsby develop",
    "start": "gatsby develop",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.0.7",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "gatsby": "^5.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^6.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6"
  }
```

I run
`npm run develop`. But it does not work getting into playground mode.

I tried installing dotenv.

added

```
 require('dotenv').config({
    path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
  });
```

to `gatsby-config.js`.

Then assigned `GATSBY_GRAPHQL_IDE=playground` into `env.development`.

Ran `npm run develop`.

Still no luck.

I also tried running simple `GATSBY_GRAPHQL_IDE=playground gatsby develop`. Didn't help either.

It actually worked after changing Gatsby version to ^4.21.1 and running `npm install`.

What could be the problem? Is Playground still present in 5.0.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playground was removed from version 5.

From [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/migrating-from-v4-to-v5/)

> **Removal of GraphQL Playground**
> Maybe you didn’t know, but Gatsby supported GraphQL Playground as an alternative to GraphiQL for some time now. With Gatsby 5 we’ve updated GraphiQL to v2 which has feature parity with GraphQL Playground. Thus we removed the GATSBY_GRAPHQL_IDE environment variable and GraphQL Playground. Visit the GraphiQL guide to learn more about GraphiQL v2.